# Move Logo from header content to panel header

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

**Magento 2 Luna Theme**

How can I move the logo from the **header content** div class to the **panel header** class so that the logo would move up to be on the same line as

Default welcome message!  Sign In   Create an Account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your custom theme by inheriting the default Luma theme at below location

> Magento_root/app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{packeage}

You can refer this [link for that](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)

Then create default.xml at below lcation

> Magento_root/app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{packeage}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

In your default.xml file put the below given code there

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="header.panel" before="header.links"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

run the below commands from the terminal from your Magento_root directory to register your theme there in magento

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Go to the **`admin > CONTENT > Design Configuration > Select the store view`** default it is **Default Store View**

From the `Default theme > drop-down` select your custom theme & click **Save Configuration**

Run below commands to deploy your content there

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f    
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now you can do any of your front-end changes from here!

Thank You!